# How does one make a Telegram MTProto protocol api call?

Tags: c#, telegram, mtproto

For instance to call/wrap the `auth.sentCode` method (link below):

https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode

I have tried:

```
var url = "https://149.154.167.40";  
var data = "(auth.sendCode \"PHONE_CODE+NO\" 0 APP_ID \"SECRET_HASH\" \"en\")";  
using (var wc = new WebClient())  
{  
var result = wc.UploadData(url, GetBytes(data));  
}
```

I get this exception (and inner exception)

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send.   (Authentication failed because the remote party has closed
>   the transport stream.)

Comment: I have no experience with this protocol, but most of the time I see exceptions like that it's an SSL/TLS issue. I see you're using a hard-coded IP - is it possible there's self-signed certificates that your app is rejecting? (Alternatively: does that endpoint definitely support https? I've gotten similar errors from sending https requests to an http endpoint.)

Comment: i think till now no example, just unimplemented lib's at githhub

Comment: I have posted some code (in vb.net) to get you started here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You an get started with [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080)

You would need to understand how to generate an **AuthKey** first.

The Telegram-API documentation is not very well written, but if you keep studying it... you eventually get the hand of it.

Working through generating the AuthKey would help you build up a pattern and functions that you can then use to tackle the rest of the API

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to access to `https://149.154.167.40` via a Web Browser, you can see that the https protocol is not enabled. If you look at [here](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram/blob/master/app/js/lib/mtproto.js#L11), there are a list of subdomains that implements https, you could try one of those to make your api request. I'm not really sure that telegram blocks your request due to the CROSS-ORIGIN policy, because the `access-control-allow-origin:*` header is present in the response. If that doesn't work, you could implement your own handshake like the android application does in [here](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/9d113ccb7a109954f73260ecfbe5cd8467e2f7a8/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/HandshakeAction.java). I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp). To authenticate user, just run this code

```
   var hash = await client.SendCodeRequest(phoneNumber);

   var code = "1234"; //code that you receive from Telegram 

   var user = await client.MakeAuth(phoneNumber, hash, code);
```